# Find x cubed with half adder

Tags: adder

My excercise is the following:

```
Make a circuit which outputs X^3 of two bit input of X.
Use the lowest number of HALF ADDERS as you can.
```

I don't really understand how to compute x cubed with half adders.

Any hints or help is appriciated.

Comment: That's a good exercise! I don't want to just give you the answer, I think it's better to work it out for yourself however I'll guide you a bit (no pun) in the direction. Try to write a simple binary multiplication on paper. For example 110 x 101 = 110 + 0000 + 11000. Did you notice something? The results you get for each stage of the multiplication are either 110 (shifted by the "weight" of the number multiplying it) or 0.

Comment: @user34920 thank you, I did want a hint. I'll try now.

Comment: @user34920 I do notice that whatever multiplication I make there are only 2 results possible. However, I still don't know what to do with that fact.

Comment: Here is a link that might help... http://fullchipdesign.com/binary_multiplier_digital.htm

Comment: @user34920. thank you. A full answer would be appriciated, since I didn't come with an answer.

Comment: Are you sure of the notation in the question? Normally ^ means xor rather than exponentiation in logic circuits.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham yes, I mean X cubed.

Comment: This is the same problem as you posted a few days ago: [An exercise on decoders](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116724/an-exercise-on-decoders) except you need to use a half-adder instead of a decoder. Knowing what you found out from those answers, all you need to do is look at the truth table for a [half-adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder) and you should easily have the answer. Were you not paying attention? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let the LSB of the number be \$a\$ and MSB be \$b\$. Then the number is \$2b+a\$ where, \$a,b\in\{0,1\}\$.

$$(2b+a)^3=8b^3 + 12ab^2+6a^2b+a^3$$

Since \$a,b\in\{0,1\}, \ a^3=a^2=a\$ , \$b^3=b^2=b\$ and \$a\times b = a\ AND\ b = ab\$.

$$\therefore (2b+a)^3=8b+18ab+a$$
$$=16ab+8b+2ab+a$$
$$=2^4\times ab+2^3\times b+2^2\times 0+2^1\times ab+2^0\times a$$

From this we can say that,

- the \$0^{th}\$ bit (LSB) of answer is \$a\$
- \$1^{st}\$ and \$4^{th}\$ bits are \$ab\$
- \$2^{nd}\$ bit is \$0\$
- \$3^{rd}\$ bit is \$b\$

The 'carry out' of an half adder, with inputs \$a\$ and \$b\$, will be \$ab\$. So circuit can be implemented as given below.

[image: schematic]

\$\mathtt{ba}\$ is the input and \$\mathtt{Y_4Y_3Y_2Y_1Y_0}\$ is the output (\$\mathtt{Y_0}\$ is the LSB).

Answer (score 1):

The input of the circuit is a 2 bit number (max value = 3) and the hence the maximum value at output will be 27 (a 5 bit number). The truth table of the circuit is:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccl}&\mathbf{x} & &\mathbf{b} &\mathbf{a} & &\mathbf{Y_4} &\mathbf{Y_3} &\mathbf{Y_2} &\mathbf{Y_1} &\mathbf{Y_0} & &x^3\\
\hline
&\style{color:red}{0} &\rightarrow &0 &0 &  &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\rightarrow &\style{color:red}{0}\\
&\style{color:red}{1} &\rightarrow &0 &1 & &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &\rightarrow &\style{color:red}{1}\\
&\style{color:red}{2} &\rightarrow &1 &0 & &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &\rightarrow &\style{color:red}{8}\\ 
&\style{color:red}{3} &\rightarrow &1 &1 & &1 &1 &0 &1 &1 &\rightarrow &\style{color:red}{27}\\
 \hline
& & & & & &ab &b &0 &ab &a\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The 'carry out' of an half adder, with inputs a and b, will be \$ab\$. So circuit can be implemented as given below.

[image: schematic]

\$\mathtt{ba}\$ is the input and \$\mathtt{Y_4Y_3Y_2Y_1Y_0}\$ is the output (\$\mathtt{Y_0}\$ is the LSB).